# show temporary postgres table content in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a temporary table created by a function and need to display the contents and titles of the temporary table because it's always changing, is it possible to access these types of tables in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute postgresql from Rails:

```rb
  ActiveRecord.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM my_temporary_table")
```

or, if the table name is dynamic:

```rb
  def my_temporary_table
     // some ruby to generate the table name
  end

  ActiveRecord.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM #{my_temporary_table}")
```

Of course, this generates a raw Postgresql query result, and you will need to iterate and extract the values. You can't instantiate ActiveRecord models this way, b/c the schema is ephemeral. But you can create `Struct` instances, which behave like Ruby objects.